# VB2013: Reading from text file when using .NET 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, file-io, readlines

I've written my entire project using Microsoft .NET 4.0 framework. It's entirely finished and works perfectly. Now I'm told that (for reasons I'm not sure of) it has to work with Microsoft .NET 2.0 framework.

So I've adjusted my project settings to be .NET 2.0, and I'm now getting this error:

```
'ReadLines' is not a member of 'System.IO.File'.
```

*ReadLines* is being called with:

```
For Each LangLine1 As String In File.ReadLines(strConfigFile)
    ' Read line from text file and store in variable
    strLanguage = LangLine1
Next
```

What method can I use with Microsoft .NET 2.0 to read a line from a textfile, in place of *File.ReadLines*?

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation fully describes each API call ... and which versions of .Net are compatible with that call:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In your case, the easiest approach is probably to just create your own ReadLines call - something that [reads lines of text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using File.IO streams and implements IEnumerable.

PS:
I suspect you'll run into other, more difficult problems trying to retrofit a .Net 4.0 project back to .Net 2.0.  That's a *"BIG* jump...